# change default application in tomcat 6

Tags: java, web-applications, web, tomcat6

I got an maven project that produces a war package. When I copy war to tomcat 6 webapps directory and start tomcat, I see my application is being deployed and running but when I try to go localhost I got default tomcat page displayed.
From googling around I got that I have to define context.xml file in my META-INF folder but I have no idea how can I define it. Can someone give me an example?

Thanks

Comment: are you using bean or spring?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a file called **context.xml** in your webapp/META-INF folder. With this content

```
<Context path="/yourAppName" />
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow when I'll get to work. The appName it's project name actually or *.war file name?

Comment: I think it can be whatever you want. SO you could have example.war but in context.xml you could have path="/myapp" . Tomcat will then send requests for /myapp to example.war

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to rename your webapp folder to ROOT

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want is when type in browser `http://localhost:8080` you are directed towards your application welcome page

It is quite easy to override that page. Inside $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml there is a section called  and it looks like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The default servlet attempts to load the index.* files in the order listed. You may easily override the index.jsp file by creating an index.html file at $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT. It's somewhat common for that file to contain a new static home page or a redirect to a servlet's main page. A redirect would look like:

```
 <html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://mydomain.com/some/path/to/servlet/homepage/">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

If you simply want to access you application with not the intention i explained above

http:/localhost:PortNumber//WelcomePage.html

Comment: That's not my case. I have my application with all servlets and pages. I just need the way to tell Tomcat to load my app as a default context

Comment: thats what i explained in first scenario